# Real time web app listen type event

Tags: javascript, websocket, real-time, vue.js, pusher

I've been creating a chat like web application where I use Pusher to connect clients.

The feature I want to implement is listen to an event when the user the user is chatting with is typing,so he can be notified of it.

How can I do it with Pusher and Javascript

Comment: keydown event or onchange event of the text input?

Comment: how do y send the event via websocket?